# Uploading files to sharepoint via standalone site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a question regarding sharepoints capabilities when it comes to file management. Essentially, what I'd like to do is use a file upload portal on a standalone website, that would transfer the file into a database within sharepoint. So basically it would go:

1. User is on standalone (non sharepoint) website.
2. User clicks a button on the standalone website to upload a file.
3. The file the user uploads on standalone website portal, gets stored in a sharepoint file management system (separate website)

I'm curious if this is possible? Please let me know if I need to illustrate or describe in more detail.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the help! I tried to upvote but don't have enough reputation unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standalone website can store a file on SharePoint. There are few things to note for the website.

1. Needs to authenticate to SharePoint and that account must have at least contribute permission on the SharePoint library where the file would store.
2. If the website is ASP.Net then it can utilize the SharePoint C# client object model APIs. Otherwise can utilize the SharePoint copy.asmx web service.
3. Can check SharePoint provider hosted Add-In option - though a bit complex in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible.
You can use SharePoint REST API calls in your standalone website upload button code.
You need to pass the credentials to REST API call.

Another way is you should develop a Web API or WCF calls to upload files into SharePoint library using CSOM. Deploy this on one public IP, use these calls in your upload button in standalone website page.

Hope this helps you...